# "finished with non-zero exit value 1" in android studio ,how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]
this error occur when import New project. i have import android project from one pc to another pc.
 i have tried to solve by

> clear project and re-Build Project
>    Android Studio invalid and Restarted 
>    deleted some settings folders and build folder then re-import.

Answer (score -1):

try to uncheck offline work
file -> setting -> build ->gradle -> uncheck offline work
i think that is problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please expand on your answer to explain why you think this will help to solve the OP's problem.  This is especially important when visitors come here with similar problems in the future.